# Improve mongoose query performances

Tags: regex, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to do some regex queries on MongoDB. However when I do such a query

```
this.model
  .find(filter)
  .limit(args.limit)
  .skip(args.skip)
  .sort(args.sort)
  .hint()
  .lean()
```

the time to get a result is around 3 to 5 seconds in a collection with not event 1000 documents. If I do the same query in the mongo shell it gets executed in around 100ms. I except some differences between doing the query on the db directly vs doing it from a driver, but here the delay is really huge and I don't understand why. The field I'm doing the regex against is also indexed.
I also tried to do almost the same query with the aggregation framework but with no luck

```
this.model.aggregate([{$match: filter}, {$skip: args.skip}, {$limit: args.limit}])
```

`this.model` is the mongoose model for the collection

Comment: Maybe writing the same query with aggregation framework helps.

Comment: I tried that already, however got no real benefit (it did still improved by some milliseconds, but is still too much)

Comment: Can you add that query in aggregation framework to the question? Also are you sure that 3-5 seconds are the query response time? How did you measure it?

Comment: I do a console.time before the query execution and a console.timeEnd after